# Create unique single <div> element  for all MySQL php results with particular value 

Tags: php, mysql, for-loop, nested-loops

Here is my problem. I am returning results from a mysql database and using a for loop to echo the results. Though its getting a little complicated because I am using some table data to nest inside other results. This code returns "Pablo Picasso" inside a div called "Spain", fine, but if there is "El Greco" in Spain too, then I get two "Spain" divs, rather than just the one.

So: I'd like to only return a result once for each unique value in a table column, rather than for every one.

```
$results = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$results[] = $row;
}

foreach ($results as $row)
    {
    echo "<div class=\"".$row['country']."\">".$row['country'];
    echo "<div class=\"Box\">";
    $tempCountry = $row['country'];

    foreach ($results as $row)
    {
    if ($row['country']== $tempCountry) echo "<div>artists name</div>";
    }

    echo "</div>";echo "</div>";
}
```

I'm wondering if it is the construction of the nested loop, or something else, I don't know!!! Please help

Comment: I'm trying to dynamically create this box model: <country1><box><artist1/><artist2/></box></country>  <country2><box><artist3/><artist4/></box></country>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @Kalpesh that you need to order the results by country.

Right now you have multiple nested loops when all you really should need is one. Try using just one loop to go through the data. On every iteration, check the $tempCountry value to see if it different compared to the current row's country. If it is, you need to close the current `<div>`, open a new `<div>` and update the $tempCountry value. Otherwise, echo the name of the artist.

**EDIT: Psuedocode added below**

- Retrieve data from database (the query should sort the data by country)
- Initialize $tempCountry to null
- Loop over every row

  - If $tempCountry equals this row's country

    2. Print the artist
  - Else

    1. Set $tempCountry equal to this row's Country
    2. Close the div tag
    3. Open a new div tag
    4. Print the artist

Note that you do not want to close the div tag on the first time through the loop. Also, you need to close the div tag after the loop finishes.

```
foreach ($results as $row) {

    if ($tempCountry == $row['country']) {

    echo "<div class=\"Box\">";

        echo "<div>artist</div></div>";

    }

    else {

        $tempCountry == $row['country'];

        echo "</div><div class=\"".$row['country']."\">".$row['country'];

        echo "<div class=\"Box\">";

        echo "<div>artist</div></div>";

    }

    echo "</div>";

}
```

Comment: Hi, I will try that too - I agree, I thought nesting the loop was over complicating it. Do you have example code of what you mean, please? Thanks anyway!

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't quite work. The artists names don't duplicate anymore, but I still get a parent div (country) for every artist: so I get <spain><picasso/></spain><spain><el greco/></spain>   when I really want <spain><picasso/><el greco/><spain>. Do I still need to nest loops, you think?

Comment: Could you post your updated code? This doesn't strike me as a situation that needs nested loops.

Comment: The problem is I need to build ONE div for all the results that have that value (ie country) and to nest inside that all the rows with that value (ie artists). Then loop over again for all the different rows with that value (other countries). I'm worried that its more complicated than I originally thought, like I need a multi-dimensional array or something. Thankyou for any help, btw!

Comment: You are closer, but not quite there. Look at lines 3 and 5 of your code. Notice that the if statement will always be true. The logic inside your if and else statements are also incorrect.

Comment: Sorry, that returns:`</div><div class="UK"><div class="Box"><div>artist</div></div></div>       <div class="UK"><div class="Box"><div>artist</div></div></div>       <div class="France"><div class="Box"><div>artist</div></div></div>.`           There is still one <country> div for each artist with that country value. I need just the one! :)

Comment: Alright, we're closer. My last thought is that I might have two errors: 1) In line 7 I accidentally used "==" instead of "=". 2) $tempCountry might need to be defined outside the loop in order for its value to persist.

Comment: Hey, that is so nearly there!! It only renders ONE iteration of the <country> div but still wraps the <artist> divs in <box> I need only one <box> inside the <country>. I'm still playing around with it but if you have a solution, that would be great...

Comment: Misunderstanding on my part. I thought you wanted a box for each artist. Just move the code for the box div to the same echo statement as the country div. Don't forget to move the close div tags.

Comment: I'm sorry but actually this isn't working as the first instance in the if statement renders <box>divs outside of <country> divs like this:   '<country1><artist/></country><country2><artist/></country><box><artist/></box><box><artist/></box>' I might have to re-think this entirely

Comment: I'm trying to dynamically create this box model: `<country1><box><artist1/><artist2/></box></country> <country2><box><artist3/><artist4/></box></country>`

Comment: I've cracked it!! I will post the code above. I have used   `SELECT * FROM tpo_EuropeBeta **GROUP BY** country` to create an array to build the country and another array to build inside of that. Sorry but I have nested a loop inside another but until I find a more efficient way, I'm sticking with it. Thanks for your help, though

Comment: Please note that no one should be copying this bad code.  The temporary value needs to be declared prior to looping.  The dangling conditional isn't doing anything, it should be an assignment.  It is simply bad/non-working code.

Answer (score 0):

Create an empty array outside of your loop. On output push the values of $row into the array inside of your loop. Then only output if value does not already exist in the array. You can use [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) for this.

Comment: Hi, I will try that. Can you supply an example of what you mean, though? I wasn't sure if it was the loop construction, or the use of foreach, but in_array would work I think

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found was to nest a foreach inside another, the outer loop SELECTS with a GROUP BY.
In this example I get one outer  for each country, then inside that , every person (or item) within that country (or with that column value). Really useful.

NEW CODE: SOLUTION (use GROUP BY to build outer container)

```
// create array to build group div
$country = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table GROUP BY `country`");
// create array for inner contents
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY name"); 

//array for group(countries in this instance)
$countrys = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($country)) {
$countrys[] = $row;
}
//array for inner contents
$results = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$results[] = $row;
}

$tempCountry="";
foreach ($countrys as $row)
    {   
    $tempCountry = $row['country'];

    echo "<div class=\"".$row['country']."\">";
    echo $row['country'];
    echo "<div class=\"Box\">";
    foreach ($results as $row) {
    if ($tempCountry == $row['country'])
    {
    echo"<div>inner contents of that group</div>";
    }
    }
    echo "</div>";
    echo "</div>";
    }
```

Comment: Why is there no aggregate function if you are using GROUP BY? Does this even work? I would not make two trips to the database.